# How to select from a json encoded field that contains nested data?

Tags: mysql, json, extract

The fields looks like this:

```
[{"Tester":"Bonnie","Credentials":"MS","Date":"2013-02-19"},
{"Tester":"Karen","Credentials":"Teacher","Date":"2016-01-20"}]
```

I need to select based on the year of the 'Date' value: < > or =

I have found the json_extract function and it's shortcuts such that this will get the data (from the MySQL docs) *"autowrapped as an array"* and it works:

```
json_field->"$[*].Date" returns ["2013-02-19", "2016-01-20"]
```

Great, so I has the dates from the json data, but now I need to format the WHERE. How do I select the record if either of the years is 2016 for instance?  I don't see any json function that do that.

Comment: There appears to be no solution.  For no I am going to select all the records and parse the json in php.  _shrug_

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to drop this JSON column and build another table, then you can search in your table using JOIN. JSON in column is a bad idea.

Just to answer your question:

I think this should work -

```
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(json_field->"$.Date", '%Y-%m-%d')) = '2016'
```

Comment: I would not have built a database like this, and I don't have the option of rebuilding it. Your answer does not appear to deal with the returned array of the nested data.  I need to deal with multiple dates being returned from the json_extract.